# Is there a need to create a tablespace in oracle

Tags: oracle, tablespace

Is it mandatory to create a tablespace in oracle? I do know that it will take a users tablespace by default. What difference does it make by specifying a tablespace and without one? Now i have created a schema without tablespace and be defualt it is in users tablespace , what are the steps to take to move my objects and datas from default to one custom tablespace.Please suggest

Comment: You have functions like `ALTER TABLE <TABLE NAME to be moved> MOVE TABLESPACE <destination TABLESPACE NAME>` to move data. Tablespace management becomes more exciting when you have thousands of tables and TBytes of data.

Comment: @ Wernfried Domscheit : Wow, thanks a ton, it worked, can you please suggest on how to move the constraint related and index related tablespace

Comment: Clearly creating additional tablespaces isn't mandatory, from what you have already done. [Read about having multiple tablespaces](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/tspaces.htm#ADMIN11357); and [the concepts guide on tablespaces](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/logical.htm#CNCPT402).

Comment: For Index it is like `Alter index <index-name> rebuild tablespace <new-tablespace>;`. Constraints, triggers, etc. are just defined in SYSTEM tablespace, those you cannot move.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply rename USERS tablespace if you dislike its name.

```
alter tablespace USERS rename to COOLNAME;
```

If you want also to rename files then you need to offline tablespace and rename them.
To know the names you can select from dba_data_files or v$datafile

```
alter tablespace COOLNAME OFFLINE; 

move file at OS level..
host mv /oracle/users01.dbf /oracle/coolname01.dbf
alter database rename file '/oracle/users01.dbf' to '/oracle/coolname01.dbf';

alter tablespace COOLNAME online;
```

If you need to move objects to another tablespace you should use move and rebuild DDL. Here is some useful queries to generate DDLs.

```
select 'alter table ' || OWNER || '.' || SEGMENT_NAME || ' move tablespace COOLNAME;' from dba_segments where OWNER='YOURUSER' and SEGMENT_TYPE='TABLE' and TABLESPACE_NAME='USERS';

select 'alter index ' || OWNER || '.' || SEGMENT_NAME || ' rebuild tablespace COOLNAME;' from dba_segments where OWNER='YOURUSER' and SEGMENT_TYPE='INDEX' and TABLESPACE_NAME='USERS';
```